# Calculating Feynman amplitude for closed two loop diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, fermions

Could someone explain or post a link for how one calculates the Feynman amplitudes for closed two loop diagrams?

[image: Feynman diagram for the closed two-loops]

This is in QED with the same fermion in both loops and a photon connecting them.

Comment: Well what have you tried on your own?

Comment: I think I do get how to set up the different factors now, but I am a little unsure how the energy-momentum conservation (delta distributions) should look in diagram A. Say the fermion line on the left has 4-momentum p (going into the vertex from the top) and the photon k (going out of the vertex), should the argument in the delta distribution be (p-k) or (p-p-k)?

I know that diagram A will become zero, but am just curious how it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply the contributions for QED vertices and internal lines. See here: http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2009s.homeworks/QED.pdf

A loop is one internal fermion and one internal antifermion line; here you must involve an integral over $d^4q$ where $q$ is the positron 4-momentum. The integral goes over the product of fermion and antifermion contribution. Imply energy-momentum conservation in delta distribution.

Example: Diagram A has two fermion lines, two antifermion lines, one photon line and two vertices.